# Ruling on being friend with a Muslim who does not pray

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, friendship

What is the ruling in Islam for being friend with a Muslim who does not pray and/or is habituated in lying and deceiving people.

Which Muslims can we take as friends and whom we can not?

Reference from Quran and Sahih Hadith will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) ordered us to inquire about the choice of companionship, and the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) forbade us to accompany the non-believers and those who were unfaithful. He said(peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): someone is on the religion of his friend, this someone must see who is really friend with, in Arabic "[قال صلى الله عليه وسلم: المرء على دين خليله فلينظر أحدكم من يخالل](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/367)" He also said peace be upon him: accompany only a believer, and let your food be eaten only by a good person, in Arabic "[لا تصاحب إلا مؤمنا، ولا يأكل طعامك إلا تقي](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/366)". Narrated by Ahmad, Abu Daoud and al-Tirmidhi.

It is not appropriate to take those who do not pray as friends, but in the other hand we should be away from them, but we should give them advices and guide them to the right way, the way of Allah.

This does not mean that eating from their food and dealing with them in life is haraam(forbidden), but we want to note that the companionship that someone takes for himself is influenced by them, that is why it must be well chosen. As for those who make relationship with the disobedient and even infidels should advise them and preach them without being affected by them because  treating them this whay is better than their abandonment.

If advising him does not go well with him, leaving  him would be a punishment for him. If he does not benefit from that, it is not good for you to accompany him. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:The good and the bad are like the owner of the musk and al-Haddad(the Blacksmith), the musk you either buy it or find its smell, but the Blacksmith's
kir it either burn your body or your dress or find a malicious smell. Agreed upon, this is a phrase for Muslim and Boukhari, in Arabic "قال الإمام مسلم رحمه الله في كتاب البر والصلة والآداب من صحيحه: حدثنا أبو بكر بن أبي شيبة حدثنا سفيان بن عيينة عن بريد بن عبد الله عن جده عن أبي موسى عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم (ح) وحدثنا محمد بن العلاء الهمداني ـ واللفظ له ـ حدثنا أبو أسامة عن بريد عن أبي بردة عن أبي موسى عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: [((إنما مثل الجليس الصالح والجليس السوء كحامل المسك ونافخ الكير، فحامل المسك إما أن يحذيك وإما أن تبتاع منه وإما أن تجد منه ريحاً طيبة، ونافخ الكير إما أن يحرق ثيابك، وإما أن تجد ريحاً خبيثة))](http://www.ajurry.com/vb/showthread.php?t=21609)

In Sahih Al Boukhari:[حدثنا موسى بن إسماعيل حدثنا عبد الواحد حدثنا أبو بردة بن عبد الله قال: سمعت أبا بردة بن أبي موسى عن أبيه رضي الله عنه قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم : ((مثل الجليس الصالح والجليس السوء كمثل صاحب المسك وكير الحداد، لا يعدمك من صاحب المسك إما تشتريه أو تجد ريحه، وكير الحداد يحرق بيتك أو ثوبك أو تجد منه ريحاً خبيثة))](http://www.ajurry.com/vb/showthread.php?t=21609)

Comment: thanks for the advice. This answers my question. However, can you please add some stories from Sahabah (ra) and the moral of the story regarding this issue.

Comment: This is only one perspective how about "Invite to the way of your Lord with wisdom and good instruction" Qur'an(16:125) and "Al-Din is a name of sincerity and well wishing."? https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/103 and ""By Allah, if a single person is guided by Allah through you, it will be better for you than a whole lot of red camels." (al-Bukhari and Muslim) the point is what is your intention in this relation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I agree with you, i have edited it.

Comment: I thought over it, and as per Quran and Hadith, I am abandoning him for the time being. If he start praying then I will reconsider my decision. I can not take responsibility for whoever walks by. I might think that I will be the source of his Hedayat, but it might turn out he is the source of my gumrahi and loss. My Eman is weak and I can not take that risk.

Comment: @blueray, Yes i agree with you on this decision, do it and from time to time if he asks you why you are doing this tell him it is because my Islam and relegion said that i must be friend only with believers who respect God's orders and his prophet(Peace be upon him).

Comment: Please provide reference in English too. Thank you